# How to obtain Offset of Kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Working with Kafka(v2.11-0.10.1.0)-spark-streaming(v-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7).

I have Kafka Producer and Spark-streaming consumer to produce and consume. All works fine till I stop consumer(for approx 2-min) and start again. The consumer starts and reads data, absolutely perfect. But, I'm lost with the 2-min data, where consumer was off.

Kafka consumer/server.properties are unchanged.

Kafka producer with properties:

```
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("bootstrap.servers", AppCoding.KAFKA_HOST);
            properties.put("auto.create.topics.enable", true);
            properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
            properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
            properties.put("retries", 1);
            logger.info("Initializing Kafka Producer.");
            Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(AppCoding.KAFKA_TOPIC, "", documentAsString));
```

Consuming using Spark-streaming api as:

```
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster(args[4]).setAppName("Streaming");

        // Create the context with 60 seconds batch size
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(60000 * 5));

        //input arguments:localhost:2181 sparkS incoming 10 local[*]

        Set<String> topicsSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(args[2].split(";")));
        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", args[0]);
        //input arguments: localhost:9092 "" incoming 10 local[*]

        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> kafkaStream =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, 
                        String.class,
                        String.class,
                        StringDecoder.class,
                        StringDecoder.class,
                        kafkaParams,
                        topicsSet);
```

On the other end i have been using ActiveMQ. While ActiveMQ Consumer could fetch me the data while its off. 
Help me out if there's a confuguration problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka, consumers actually have no direct relationship with producers. Each consumer has an offset which tracks what has been consumed in the partitions. If a consumer has no offset tracked, Kafka will automatically reset its offset to the largest one because of the default value of config 'auto.offset.reset'. In your case, when the brand-new consumer is started, due to the default policy, it does not see the messages produced previously. You could set 'auto.offset.reset' to earliest (for new consumer) or smallest (for old consumer).

Comment: Thanks. There's no such offset value as earliest. I should only use small/largest. Smallest:- gives all the data everytime I start the consumer. Program would end up executing same data again and again. Largest:- anyway gives the latest, is the default value. I'm looking for an approach that consumer could read from where it left.

Comment: The consumer will read from where it left automatically. Config 'auto.offset.reset' is for the cases of no init offset or out-of-range offset.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka maintains offset per partition per record basis. While consumer was off for 2 minute duration, offset value would be stored in topic metadata for new-consumer, and again when the consumer is started back after 2minutes, it would read last offset which was stored in kafka topic.

I think what you need to check is `kafka broker data retention policy` if it is less than 2 minutes , data would be lost , if data corresponding to offset is not present , it would start reading from  latest as by default value is set to latest `auto.offset.reset=latest` for new data arriving.

I would suggest to check and change kafka data retention policy accordingly if it is less than 2 minutes